# WordPress for java developer, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, java, wordpress, web

I am a Java developer and I know Rest APIs. But what if I want to make great webpages using website building tools like WordPress and then with Rest API I can connect with my backend server.

Will that be a viable solution or I should look for something else?

On a very basic research I got to know that wordpress runs on PHP, but I am not looking to learn PHP at this point of time.

I am looking for the below things :

**1** - Some tool which helps in building rich HTML page, that has drag
    and drop options.
 **2** - I am thinking to use Spring boot for
    configuring Rest API.

Basically I am looking for some suggestions in building good websites having knowledge of Java. (And yes I still need to learn Ajax and Javascript.)

I might be absolutely wrong on what I am looking, but any suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A REST client (in your case a website) doesn't care what programming languages/technologies were used to create the server. You can have a server hosting a WordPress website (PHP) and have another server for your REST API created in Java or whatever other language you might want to use. If you want to make REST calls from your WordPress server (e.g. for server-side rendering), you'll need to use PHP. The more likely scenario is that the website makes REST requests from the browser, in which case you'll need to use JavaScript.